# ShowWindow is not called when parent window is maximized

Tags: c++, mfc, showwindow

I have a modal window(1st window) inside which another window(2nd window) gets called, when 1st window is maximized it does not call for ShowWindow() function which in turn 2nd window is not launched by default and secondly when the 1st window is restored the 2nd window is launched i.e ShowWindow() is called.

Can someone tell me why when window is maximized ShowWindow() is not called? When I explicitly pass WM_SHOWWINDOW by postmessage() in initDialog() 2nd window launches.

Thanks,

Comment: How are you maximising the main window?

Comment: main window is derived from CDialog, we are no where explicitly passing wm_maximize. I think its taken care by CDialog only. Did I answered your question?

Comment: manually maximizing it.